# MySQL Write Lock Priority

Tags: mysql, table-locking

I'm curious about write locks with MySQL and how they are prioritized with eachother. Specifically, I'm wondering if "low priority write" locks have lower priority than "normal" write locks, or if they are equal. The only documentation I can find states that the low priority locks have lower priority than read locks, allowing read locks to process first. But I can't find anything that states how they relate to other write locks.

The point of this is that I'm looking for a way to "prioritize" write locks, and wondering if just the standard low priority lock will do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The manual has it all](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html):

> A request for a LOW_PRIORITY WRITE lock, by contrast, permits subsequent READ lock requests by other sessions to be satisfied first **if they occur while the LOW_PRIORITY WRITE request is waiting** *[to be granted]*.

Nothing is mentioned about an effect on `WRITE` lock requests, so the `LOW_PRIORITY` modifier has no effect on concurrent them.

[Beware, though](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html):

> The LOW_PRIORITY modifier has no effect as of MySQL 5.5.3

[And](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html):

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, it is deprecated and its use produces a warning. Use WRITE without LOW_PRIORITY instead.

Comment: Thanks for the note on deprecation, I missed that when reading the manual before. This though is the part I'm wondering about still: `If a session issues a LOCK TABLES statement to acquire a lock while already holding locks, its existing locks are released implicitly before the new locks are granted.` I'm concerned about the time between the implicit release of prior locks and the new locks. If another session had requested a write lock before the implicit release, will the second session be granted the lock before the first?

Comment: Yes, regardless of the use of `LOW_PRIORITY`. It is easy to verify on a test table.